# How to run "brew" command in windows..?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, reactjs, command

It shows "**'brew' is not recognized as an internal or external command**" in windows command prompt.

[image]

I am trying to install [codeigniter-reactjs-example](https://github.com/makasimenator/codeigniter-reactjs-example) from **github**, where first command is `brew`.
How to run this command to install that project in Windows..?

Comment: That example is on an OS X machine. Homebrew is a package manager for Mac OS X

Comment: @Andrew Li... Then how to install in windows..?

Comment: You don't, Homebrew is only for Mac.

Comment: you have to install it manually, there is no package manager in windows

Comment: You could either use the alternatives mentioned in comments (and [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/homebrew-install-on-windows-os)) or set up a virtual machine that supports the `brew` package manager

Comment: scoop is pretty much the closest thing you can find on Windows at the moment.

Comment: There is something called chocolatey. It does the same thing.

Comment: With Homebrew 2.0 and Windows 10 WSL, you now have brew "on Windows": see [my answer below](https://github.com/Linuxbrew/homebrew-core)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

**Edit:** Homebrew is also usable on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) [since version 2.0.0](https://brew.sh/2019/02/02/homebrew-2.0.0/) (released February 2019), as detailed by [@VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc)'s [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44886348/how-to-run-brew-command-in-windows/54524742#54524742). The instructions for installation/use are available at:

- https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux

---

Homebrew is MacOS only command line installer application and it doesn't exist for Windows.

The Windows alternatives are:

- [Winget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/)
- [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/)
- [Npackd](https://npackd.appspot.com/)
- [Scoop](https://scoop.sh/)
- [OneGet for Windows 10](https://github.com/OneGet/oneget)

Source: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/homebrew-install-on-windows-os

Comment: Looks like this answer is copy and pasted from another site (word for word): https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/homebrew-install-on-windows-os. Please make sure to cite your source if you are referencing something else.

Comment: What about `winget`?

Answer (score 10):

> It shows "'brew' is not recognized as an internal or external command" in windows command prompt.

Not anymore, 19 months later (Feb. 2019, compared to July 2017)

At least, not on Windows 10, in a [WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) session.
As [mentioned by Mike McQuaid](https://twitter.com/MikeMcQuaid/status/1091643370198519808)

> Homebrew 2.0.0 has been released (at @FOSDEM!) **with official Linux and Windows 10 WSL support**, `brew cleanup` running automatically (opt-out with `HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP`), no more options in Homebrew/core and no longer running on OS X 10.8 and older.

See [Homebrew 2.0.0](https://brew.sh/2019/02/02/homebrew-2.0.0/).

> “Homebrew on Linux” is called “`Linuxbrew`”.
>   You can install it in your home directory, so it does not require `sudo`, and use it to install software that your host distribution’s package manager does not provide. 
>   `Linuxbrew` uses its own repository for formulae: [`Linuxbrew/homebrew-core`](https://github.com/Linuxbrew/homebrew-core).

So again, this is not *native* Windows support, but Linux (through the WSL layer, on Windows 10).

Answer (score 2):

You can **Install** **Brew** on windows subsystem i.e in Ubuntu or Kali linux by following these steps.

```
1: $ sudo apt-get install build-essential procps curl file git -y
2: $ /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
3: $ echo 'eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /home/$USER/.profile
eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
4: $ brew update
```

I have installed in both the linux(Windows subsystem)

To **Upgrade**

```
$ brew upgrade PACKAGE
```

To **Uninstall**

```
$ brew uninstall PACKAGE
```

Finally, if you ever want to remove Homebrew from Linux, the command is:

```
$ /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, Homebrew is a package manager for OSX, much like Aptitude in linux. You can't install Homebrew on Windows and never will be able to so you need to find a new way to accomplish what you are doing. I think you're trying to work with Google's V8 Javascript engine so why not try:
https://github.com/phpv8/v8js

Comment: Tried your link, there is no accurate procedure to install V8Js. But used another [link](https://blog.xenokore.com/how-to-install-v8js-for-php-on-windows/) which one i used to install

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew is a package manager for OS X. Windows can't use Homebrew. Even if there was a way to get pass that, the packages wouldn't work.

This link below might help you find an alternative.

http://alternativeto.net/software/homebrew/

Answer (score -1):

Use this

- Download [git bash](https://git-scm.com/download/win)
- Run below command, this will install homebrew to your PC
- now this can help you run brew command

```
bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

- If you want to run directly without bash then It can be done using cmd also
- If following with cmd then you need to add the location of homebrew downloaded folder to your environment path variables

Try this in windows CMD

```
curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh
```

Now add this folder location  `"C:\Users\[NAME]\homebrew\"` to path variable

TO add in Path Variables Follow below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: it installs homebrew in your PC[WINDOWS]

Comment: Now you can run brew command [Provided You add it in your path variable]

Comment: doesn't work. I get this error: "Homebrew is only supported on macOS and Linux"

Comment: we shouldn't, It doesn't work, window's user have alternative tool like `chocolatey` https://chocolatey.org/

Comment: Yes I know we can use choco, or scoop for windows, but this brew worked on my PC 

Comment: I guess I have installed git cmd and linux subsystem