# How do you update "yarn" to the latest version, 1.13.0?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I tried "npm update yarn -g" and "npm intall yarn -g", but the yarn verison is still 1.12.3.

I run the command in a empty folder, please see below. Thank you.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.320]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

D:\test>dir
 Volume in drive D is D
 Volume Serial Number is 18E2-7E00

 Directory of D:\test

01/16/2019  10:38 PM    <DIR>          .
01/16/2019  10:38 PM    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  467,370,369,024 bytes free

D:\test>npm update yarn -g

D:\test>yarn -v
1.12.3

D:\test>npm install yarn -g
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn -> C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\bin\yarn.js
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarnpkg -> C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\bin\yarn.js
+ yarn@1.13.0
updated 1 package in 0.469s

D:\test>yarn -v
1.12.3

D:\test>npm -v
6.4.1

D:\test>
```

Comment: yarn upgrade --latest

Comment: you can check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55278430/2628378

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There is a known bug on `npm update yarn -g` here is the related GitHub [issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/18989) so you should use this instead:

```
npm install -g yarn
```

Alternatively, you can install `brew` first than update trough `brew` like this:

```
brew upgrade yarn
```

If you're using Windows you can find a `brew` [alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44886348/how-to-run-brew-command-in-windows), such as `choco`, and update with like this:

```
choco upgrade yarn
```

Comment: Npm install -g yarn no longer does anything if you already have yarn installed globally.  It will leave it at the old minor version.

Answer (score 6):

The question shows that yarn has been upgraded with `npm install yarn -g` to 1.13.0 but the yarn command is still showing an older version

```
D:\test>yarn -v
1.12.3
```

The most likely problem is because the executed yarn version is as expected, `C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn`. Check which version of yarn you are invoking with

```
D:\test>where yarn
```

### Upgrading Yarn

[@Whatatimetobealive's answer is the best option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54228798/399759) to upgrade yarn. If for some reason you cannot use `choco`, `brew`, `npm` or your package manager to install yarn, you can try using `yarn` itself.

```
$ yarn global add yarn
```

Unfortunately we cannot use yarn to update itself [until the `yarn self-update` command is fixed](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/self-update/).

Comment: `yarn global add yarn` does the job

Comment: This is the warning coming out of the command `yarn global add yarn`
`warning Installing Yarn via Yarn will result in you having two separate versions of Yarn installed at the same time, which is not recommended. To update Yarn please follow https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install`

Answer (score 2):

Neither through the [npm solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54228798/6225838) nor with [`yarn global` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54304219/6225838) I could get it properly updated. With the former it remained at the old version (as the question states) and the latter gave the warning:

> Installing Yarn via Yarn will result in you having **two separate versions of Yarn installed at the same time**, which is not recommended.

And indeed, by doing `where yarn`:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn
C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.cmd
C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.js
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\yarn
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\yarn.cmd
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.cmd
```

Previously it was only installed in *Program Files* and after `yarn global add yarn` the new version went to *AppData*, but according to `yarn -v` the one being used was still the old one.

Therefore, using windows "Add or remove programs", I removed yarn manually which made the old version (on *Program Files*) to be removed leaving just the *AppData* one (latest version at this time: 1.22.4).

As the warning also recommended:

> To update Yarn please follow **https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install**

As the people developing yarn suggest, I suppose things are less likely to go wrong using the installer.

Answer (score 1):

Firsly, you need to know the version you wanted, using `npm view yarn versions`

It'll show you list of yarn version like this.

```
[
  '0.1.0',       '0.1.1',       '0.1.2',  '0.1.3',  '0.15.1',
  '0.16.0',      '0.16.1',      '0.17.0', '0.17.2', '0.17.3',
  '0.17.4',      '0.17.5',      '0.17.6', '0.17.7', '0.17.8',
  '0.17.9',      '0.17.10',     '0.18.0', '0.18.1', '0.18.2',
  '0.19.0',      '0.19.1',      '0.20.0', '0.20.3', '0.20.4',
  '0.21.0',      '0.21.1',      '0.21.2', '0.21.3', '0.22.0',
  '0.23.0',      '0.23.1',      '0.23.2', '0.23.3', '0.23.4',
  '0.24.0',      '0.24.1',      '0.24.2', '0.24.3', '0.24.4',
  '0.24.5',      '0.24.6',      '0.25.1', '0.25.2', '0.25.3',
  '0.25.4',      '0.26.0',      '0.26.1', '0.27.0', '0.27.1',
  '0.27.2',      '0.27.3',      '0.27.4', '0.27.5', '0.28.1',
  '0.28.4',      '1.0.0',       '1.0.1',  '1.0.2',  '1.1.0',
  '1.2.0',       '1.2.1',       '1.3.1',  '1.3.2',  '1.4.0',
  '1.5.0',       '1.5.1',       '1.6.0',  '1.7.0',  '1.8.0',
  '1.9.1',       '1.9.2',       '1.9.4',  '1.10.0', '1.10.1',
  '1.11.0',      '1.11.1',      '1.12.0', '1.12.1', '1.12.3',
  '1.13.0',      '1.14.0',      '1.15.0', '1.15.1', '1.15.2',
  '1.16.0',      '1.17.0',      '1.17.1', '1.17.2', '1.17.3',
  '1.18.0',      '1.19.0',      '1.19.1', '1.19.2', '1.21.0',
  '1.21.1',      '1.22.0',      '1.22.1', '1.22.4', '1.22.5',
  '1.22.6',      '1.22.7',      '1.22.8', '1.22.9', '1.22.10',
  '2.0.0-rc.24', '2.0.0-rc.27'
]
```

Then you can update with the following template.
`npm install -g yarn@<version>`

For example
`npm install -g yarn@2.0.0-rc.24`

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade, download the latest installer at "https://yarnpkg.com/latest.msi"

But for some reason the download speed is slow.