# How to run npm webpack vue project on both Windows and Mac?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, webpack

I took a Vue 2 online course and it did show (but didn't really explain) how to install node.js, npm and vue. Currently using vue-cli to set up my project using `vue init webpack-simple`. Problem is I have a Windows desktop and a Mac laptop. I'm using Box cloud on both but I need to have 2 separate folders for the same project. Basically, project-1-windows and project-1-mac.

I can't run `npm run dev` on the project-1-mac while on Windows 10 and vice versa. The only way I know to run both is to delete the node_modules folder and run `npm install`. However it takes a while for the files to download. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: You shouldn't sync the node_modules directory between the machines, not all dependencies are cross-platform. Use actual source control (e.g. git) then you can ignore the directory (e.g. with .gitignore).

Comment: are you saying node_modules directory should be saved on the disk while the rest of the files can be on the cloud?

Comment: No. node_modules will be created dynamically in new installations using npm install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want either [GitHub](https://github.com/)/[BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/)/friends or (for much more complex set-ups) [Docker](https://www.docker.com/).

I will explain only the first (easier) option. To set-up docker, you rather go to its docks.

So, for GitHub/BitBucket/friends way, you need some one-time set-up (you have to do all of this in terminal of your machine. I don't go too deep into details because you may find corresponding docks for each thing easily by googling it).

1. Install git if needed on both machines. On mac, you just run `git --version` in terminal. It'll either show the version of installed git or will ask if you want to install git together with other developer tools.
2. Install [brew](https://brew.sh/) on Mac, install [any of these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44886436/9430588) on Windows. These are just package managers. *Use them to install nvm*.
3. Install [nvm](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/nvm) (it's node version manager, arguably the most convenient way to manage node.js installations) on both machines.
4. Use nvm to install node.js (npm comes bundled with it) on both machines. That's it! One-time set-up done. Run `node -v && npm -v` to check that both are installed.

Now, to start each project you would do the following:

1. Create a repo (which is like a folder but on GitHub/BitBucket server) that you may freely access from any device that has internet connection.
2. Start project on any of your machines with something like `npm init` or `vue init webpack-simple` or whatever you feel comfortable with.
3. Run `git init`
4. When you do changes, [commit & push them](https://www.google.com/amp/s/product.hubspot.com/blog/git-and-github-tutorial-for-beginners%3Fhs_amp%3Dtrue) into your online repo.
5. [Avoid committing files that might be auto-regenerated](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/gitignore), they simply don't worth storing.
6. You may use any `npm` commands.
7. When you want to continue working on another machine, simply `git clone` your existing repo, run `npm install` and you are done.
8. Commit changes if needed.
9. `git pull` changes to another device if needed